# How to load different html pages with the same url?

Tags: html, ajax, django

I have three functions in views.py and corresponding three html pages to render those views. All three views are made to render a table that contains different attributes. My purpose is to drill down the row contents of the first table and successively the second table. Since I have seperate view function I need to provide them separate URL's. My aim is to have one URL and render the multiple HTML pages. I am not much familiar with ajax. Is there a way to achieve this in ajax or in some other way?
Please guide to sort out this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain your problem with some codes you have written?

Comment: You may want to use just one view function and use HTML query parameters. `http://myserver/my/view?foo=1&bar=baz` will dispatch to `view` which can access `foo=request.GET.get('foo',None)` and so on. You can use a template to generate a table at the various levels  with lots of clickable hyperlinks, all to the same view but with different query parameters.